# How quickly can you type this unary string?

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, integer

If I want to type the string `aaa`, the least keystrokes I can type it in is 3: `a a a`. But if I want to type the string `aaaaaa`, I can do it in 5: `a a a ctrl-c ctrl-v`, where the `ctrl-c` refers to copying `aaa` and the `ctrl-v` refers to pasting it.

Specifically, starting with an empty "buffer" and an empty "clipboard":

- The keystroke `a` appends an `a` to the buffer.
- `ctrl-c` takes some substring of the buffer and stores it into the clipboard. I'll notate it as `ctrl-c(5)` or similar to refer to 5 characters being stored. Only one string can be stored into the clipboard, and storing overwrites previous content.
- `ctrl-v` appends the clipboard to the buffer.

Each of these counts as one keystroke.

With a larger example, the least keystrokes 17 `a`s can be typed in is 8:

```
a a a ctrl-c(3) ctrl-v ctrl-v ctrl-c(8) ctrl-v
```

Your challenge is to, given a number `n`, return the number of keystrokes required to type `n` `a`s. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

### Testcases

These are done by hand, so tell me if any of these are wrong. Also, this [doesn't appear](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C5%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C8%2C8%2C8%2C8%2C8&language=english&go=Search) to be on OEIS. I've written some not-quite-functional [python code](https://tio.run/##jVPLbtswELzzKwbOhbTZok4urRH3RwQiYCwqJiqTEkm1Ngp/u8uHZMtNCvQk7nJmdna56k5hb83T185dLo2zBzSD2QVrWw996KwLcKoedooc5PGlVeYt7LHFN0K00eHFBxlUjH8v5GKDLxyLNn3PeICMaYmdHUzgaGNQyKQf1JAo1U1AkJ/a66DqmPYqUEZIrRoYdRwBnhYyRw7ZhkA3oDmoYmmB71s8pTSi3TA4gyqdgWU1epthl6A/sMKa8ex2vGnjzQr54ozGunjUBk6aN0XXfHSPTzM4g@D/rhK1PtB/fKf9yGcslvq6J@B5Gt1U7YNS63Hyd9T1OeEFuY7k/4mCkM56r1/b/FQx/LXX8Zwfb0Oi7vSMZTtoKw@vtcSR47TBMWqcOKr5A97Wh6NneQh9GkLWEREs2Ey18hnhr4gyF0c9g7EhpceVie39Bc1bMN5@lnVNCy/JZ5XS5XaLm6VMwbXjVTKQJyTmrVZ9X3z3d7b6vig@zwSTq4fOaRNoxvHJUFxtUvLzgfj4n6maVsu0/ZMNJhi7XP4A) to find all possible outputs for a given length.

The first 30 terms of the sequence are:

```
1,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,9,10,10,10
```

And some more specific ones, with examples:

```
11 -> 7 (a a a ctrl-c(3) ctrl-v ctrl-c(5) ctrl-v)
17 -> 8 (a a a ctrl-c(3) ctrl-v ctrl-v ctrl-c(8) ctrl-v)
25 -> 9 (a a a ctrl-c(3) ctrl-v ctrl-v ctrl-c(8) ctrl-v ctrl-v, the python code doesn't find this one)
75 -> 12 (a a a ctrl-c(3) ctrl-v ctrl-v ctrl-c(9) ctrl-v ctrl-v ctrl-c(24) ctrl-v ctrl-v, python code also misses this one)
```

Comment: Your exemple seem to imply that the mouse selection and clicking [at the end, to both unselect and choose a spot] do not count as keystrokes? My Vim blood boils ^^

Comment: I think this can be formulated as dynamic programming, where the state is the current length of string as well as the length in the buffer.

Comment: @OlivierDulac: yeah, seriously.  If an arbitrary amount of mouse work is allowed, just middle-click to paste, or bring up a right-click context menu to copy and paste.  I assumed when reading at first that the entire textbox was the "selection" copied by control-c, since that's the only thing plausible with just a keyboard without having hit any shift-arrow keys or even ctrl-a.  Being able to select precisely 24 characters somehow, for the same time cost as hitting `a` or ctrl-v is total nonsense.  This needs a new title and framing to make any sense as an application of this math problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes this a *simplified* problem and not intended to be seen as *any* "application of [a] math problem." This is *not* any real world problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes They probably don't allow using the autorepeat on the keyboard either.

Answer (score 8):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 47 bytes

- -1 by Arnauld.

```javascript
f=x=>x<6?x:Math.min(f(x+1>>1)+2,f(x-=x/3<<1)+3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDsIgEEDRq8ySCbYWSVwoQ0/gIUgtOqYyTduYuT2ye3/xP@mX9mnj9eiKPOdaMylFDddRb490vPsvF5ONWhejQ3s5NXekZx9CS481ywaGgcDdgSEQ@KHBWoRJyi7L3C/yMtw@Rqx/)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x*(x<6)or min(f(x-x/2)+2,f(x-x/3*2)+3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcoxCoAwDEDRq2RMtCJtwUH0MBWtBmwqxSGevgpu/8G/nvvI4mqN8xnSsgbQURvUaaBcILFgRO20d9Q686dvPniq8RsYWKAE2Te0BrylEa7CcgMbiMhUXw)

<s>I don't really ensure this function is correct. But it at least pass all testcases given.</s>

After I ask this solution on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4881219/prove-or-reject-my-solution-to-how-quickly-can-you-type-this-unary-string), [caduk](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/966819/caduk) had provided a nice prove to it. You may read [the prove by caduk on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4881417).

Anyway, the formula is

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
n & n<6 \\
\min \left\{f\left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)+2, f\left(n-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)+3 \right\} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Is it possible that you type more than `n-floor(n/2)`c and copy, as the function isn't monotone?

Comment: @l4m2 reasonable argue, but i cannot find a counterexample with n<2000 compared with the referenced implementation. So i have no idea how to either prove it or reject it.

Comment: [I tested to 116M without counterexample](https://tio.run/##NY1BDoIwFET3nGI2JiUFpJK4EIon8ASkC1JBv0FqKMEmhrMjjbh7M/@/zKOeaqsHeo1xb67Nskz1AC2rVOWBx1Y6WbrieHanSz3ekyf1TFeOi7IUih@ilWPm9llRiFDxLMyD1gxgXiUpcuTgnEJ8AsB3FhIto/UN0BWpNVrP1IJZlL6LhQKH@DnAeB/MGxVFsNF2Vt6YN4uwg2iOkBLp39Gmt6Zrks7csI3NwbwsXw)

Comment: If I understand the description correctly for 81 a's you could do: a a a c(3) v v c(9) v v c(27) v v for a total of 12 key strokes, way less then how I understand your algorithm which starts with typing either 41 or 27 a's first?

Comment: @quarague how can it be different from f(27)+3 in second part of min?

Comment: I didn't see the iteration in your description, when you write 'first type x characters' that does not mean you type x characters directly but rather you use the most efficient way to generate x characters.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 68 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,m,i=n>>1)=>i?Math.min(f(n-i,i)-~(i!=m),f(n,m,i-1),f(n-1,m)+1):n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BCsIwEETvfkW87dKkkKtl4xf4BaXIWhuNNBtpi16Kvx5rFTzNzGOGufGDx3YI98lIOnc5ewLRUQcS5yySC/sDT9cyBgEPYoIOaF4QthRR@2/V2NUaqyMWFneSB34evSLlK/URYH3SLSpyytf1GppGzbOCf6R182vixqcBmMlWVVEwY5tkTH1X9umy4OVtYZjf)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>51</s> 38 bytes

```
⊞υ⟦⁰⟧ＦＮ⊞υＥ⁺²ι⌊Ｅ⮌υ⌊Ｅμ⁺ξ⁺∨⁼π⊕ν⊕ν¬⁼πκＩ⌊⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY8/D8IgEMX3fgrGI8HEdHHoZIwmHdTG1Thgi5EItALX@O0R@sdGJu793r2Xq5/c1i1XIVTonoCMXNc3WmSP1hIoTYf@hPouLFBKZseRd1ApdJAzImmcpZEa9agluPWlacQneRMfdM3I2cL@jVw5MIy8IsgppWPcQSofS9L3InphnQCMaJLj7rTYMVKa2gotjBcNmCFAzx1V20EalqJ/89KaXpFVVhoPO@48/G6IETjQEPJNWPXqCw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses dynamic programming on the basic recurrence relation, which may be equivalent to @l4m2's approach, but I can't read it.

```
⊞υ⟦⁰⟧
```

Start with `0` keystrokes to type `0` `a`s.

```
ＦＮ
```

Loop over all numbers up to `n`.

```
⊞υＥ⁺²ι⌊Ｅ⮌υ⌊Ｅμ⁺ξ⁺∨⁼π⊕ν⊕ν¬⁼πκ
```

Loop over all clipboard sizes up to `n` and calculate the minimum number of keystrokes needed for the current number while finishing with that clipboard size. All previous entries are considered; `1` is added to the entry if it has a different clipboard size, as that means another `^C` is needed, plus the number of extra `a`s is added, unless the clipboard is of exactly the right size, in which case `1` is added, as in that case only a `^V` is needed. (The values where more than one `a` is needed are unnecessary but it's golfier to calculate and discard them.)

```
Ｉ⌊⊟υ
```

Output the minimum number of keystrokes needed to output `n` in unary.

A port of @tsh's formula using dynamic programming takes 33 bytes:

```
Ｆ⊕Ｎ⊞υ⎇‹ι⁶ι⌊Ｅ²⁺⁺²κ§υ⁻ι×⊕κ÷ι⁺²κＩ⌊⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY09DsIwDIV3TpHRkcLSAQYmBEslijL0AqE1qkWTVElcwelDWgkQHvwjf@@9bjCh82bM@e6DgNp1AS26hH3ZJ05XtjcMIKUUmuMArESLwZnwggvGCKTETipRRkOOLFtozASVEnrkCGsrx6Mgx1S7Hp@LQ0F5lbZkMf6FLmTt0plm6nFBfhbfOmx0IJfgZGKCT6z2E/D6zbna5@08vgE) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5.9, 48 bytes

```swift
let f={x in x<6 ?x:2+min(f(x-x/2),1+f(x-x/3*2))}
```

A direct port of [@tsh's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271795/118665), because I don't know how else to do this concisely.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 327 bytes

```py
R=range
def f(n):
 q,s,r=[(0,0)],[],[]
 for a,c in q:
  if a==n:r+=[c];continue
  if r and c>=min(r):continue
  if a<3:q+=[(a+1,c+1)]
  else:
   U=[(a+1,c+1)]
   for i in R(3,min(a,n-a)+1):
    for j in R(1,(n-a)//i+1):U+=[(a+i*j,c+1+j)]
   for A,B in U:
    if all(k<A or K>B for k,K in s):q+=[(A,B)];s+=[(A,B)]
 return min(r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFBj4MgEIXv/oq5CZWmum7Tja1N2mtvTTyZHgjCLtZFBXrYX@@CJK27CQdevjdvZmD4sV@9yj8GPU3XUlP1yaOGCxBI4SKCkRiiyxqlJMU3UvsTgeg1UMJAKhidB6QAWpaq0ElZs9ue9cpK9eCBOKtqgB3Lb6mQxsVfSg95MboyRJOMsCTDLh54Z7jPheofmDtL3/eKcuIDKVFrih2e/TNvA88I8mizkZ5WoYdctT4saV9xJ3L2BVUI8CN1HbofTuDY5XiePXdy8R6Dw6yuBN/25nmNQHP70ArCitOgpbIoNrzjzPIGLDcWGDXcxDgKUKAswwuxW4i37ULsXiJex6v3FEfPR5h/yy2auwWDRRKBJMbTLw)

Comment: -6 if you change `0==any(k>=A and K<=B` into `all(k<A or K>B`

Comment: @Vélimir Thank you, updated

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
f=->x{x<6?x:2-[-f[x-x/2],~f[x-x/3*2]].max}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W166iusLGzL7Cykg3WjctukK3Qt8oVqcOwjLWMoqN1ctNrKj9X6CgYainZ2hgoAnkF2iopWn@BwA)

Not very original, basically a port of tsh's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 64 bytes

A direct port of [@tsh's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271795/110802).

---

```scala
def f(x:Int):Int=if(x<6)x else 2+Math.min(f(x-x/2),1+f(x-x/3*2))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY6xTsMwEIb3PsWvqoNNCaGJhFDUCpBYkOiEmFAHE-zEKLUj-yKCqjwJSxb6Tn0bnKQDg-3z_Xefvp-jz0Ul0v50Z98_ZU7YCm1wmAFxjEeptNGmgIBqTE7aGih8aSrDDJUS_3Z-G1LR7en-Qyoo1mZPhvhwbXT4rW94C1l5iWS5FVRe7bVhoR-1ccIvV8upTC8Szs-cYzAYUPuAZsIVPsODc-L77YVcMNrxDK9GEzaj62j7bG0NsqjDAI16TvqmIg9lHbSpm1CuQuBsU5RIr8fFIWMa62iIbOjyMxETqDLMzxc6w-KgmObdnI9pNxtON9n2_fT-AQ)